# Smaller size of f.date_select boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I'm using Rail's 'f_date_select' with Twitter Boostrap, which results in the look below. However, I want the select boxes to be smaler (~ half the size).

How can I do this?

```
<%= f.label :start_date, :class => "control-label"%>
<%= f.date_select :start_date, :prompt => { :day => 'Select day', :month => 'Select month', :year => 'Select year' }  %>
<%= f.label :end_date, :class => "control-label"%>
<%= f.date_select :end_date, :prompt => { :day => 'Select day', :month => 'Select month', :year => 'Select year' }  %>
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're getting the width from the select element in bootstrap:

```
select {
  width: 220px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

To fix, add your own at the bottom of the overrides file:

```
select.date-select {
    width:auto;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

The next problem is applying the class to the date_select elements.  If you just throw :class => "date-select" in there, Rails doesn't recognize that you're trying to use both options and html_options.  Instead, you have to pass each as a hash:

```
<%= f.date_select :start_date, {:prompt => { :day => 'Select day', :month => 'Select month', :year => 'Select year' }}, {:class => 'date-select'}  %>
```

This will apply your class date-select to each of the three select objects generated.

Answer (score 1):

From memory, styling select boxes are a nightmare since they're more like browser components (i.e., they render differently in different browsers regardless of styling).

Since you're using Bootstrap though you can use [their jQuery dropdown component](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns) and style that as much as you like.

You'd have to adjust your Rails code to suit.